# Python: simple csv substring filter

Tags: python, csv

I would like to search for a substring in the rows of a csv file. Here's what I've got. I know that it is not performing the search and I'm not writing the output correctly.

```
import csv

def filterCSVfile (path):
    filterSubstrings = ['signal1', 'signal2']
    csvData = open (path)
    filereader = csv.reader(csvData, delimiter=',')

    rows = [row for row in filereader if row in filterSubstrings]

    outFileHandle = open("output.csv", "w")
    outFileHandle.write(rows)
    outFileHandle.close()

filterCSVfile('history.csv')
```

**EDIT**

The csv file contains two columns, one is a human-readable date-time, and the other is a url, like:

```
2016-02-12 15:37:15,http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt60lVB8sHo
2016-02-12 15:37:15,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt60lVB8sHo
2016-02-12 15:54:33,http://kizi.com/games/paintworld-2-monsters
2016-02-12 16:12:56,http://kizi.com/games/u/icycle
2016-02-12 16:13:03,http://kizi.com/games/u/iron-turtle
2016-02-12 16:13:46,http://www.armorgames.com/
2016-02-12 16:13:46,http://armorgames.com/
```

I would like to extract the rows that contain either 'signal1' or 'signal2' in the url, for example, http://signal1.com.

Comment: I think you searching that an entire CSV row is contained within your filters... Should probably check intersection?

Comment: The rows should contain both 'signal1' and 'signal2', or one of them?

Comment: I am filtering to keep rows that either contain 'signal1' or 'signal2' and discard all the other rows. I tried your code below and it returns an empty file.

Comment: @interwebjill, I misunderstand your question. I just edited my answer. Please try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the row,

```
rows = [row for row in filereader if row in filterSubstrings]
```

with,

```
rows = [row for row in filereader if any([word in row[1] for word in filterSubstrings])]
```

---

**Source code**

```
import csv

def filterCSVfile(path):
    filterSubstrings = set(['signal1', 'signal2'])  # for efficency reason

    with open(path, 'r') as csvData:
        filereader = csv.reader(csvData, delimiter=',')
        rows = [row for row in filereader if any([word in row[1] for word in filterSubstrings])] # change this row

    with open('output.csv', 'w') as outFileHandle
        writer = csv.writer(outFileHandle)  # get a write object
        writer.writerows(rows)

filterCSVfile('history.csv')
```

---

**Test**

The content of `history.csv`,

```
date1,http://signal1.com
2016-02-12 15:37:15,http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt60lVB8sHo
2016-02-12 15:37:15,https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wt60lVB8sHo
date2,http://signal2.com
```

Output `rows`,

```
[['date1', 'http://signal1.com'], ['date2', 'http://signal2.com']]
```

Comment: @interwebjill, you need get a write object before writing into files by using `csv.writer`. Check the updated answer.

Comment: File created! But empty. I am not looking for the intersection, but either one substring OR the other.

Comment: @interwebjill, you might add part of your csv file to your question.

Comment: @interwebjill, oops, I saw your trace. I updated my answer again. It should work right now.

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thank you.